# Select value from one row that difference TestType,The UserID and Set that value to Final_Test_Score column and GROUP BY UserID

Tags: mysql, sql

I want query from this table as image below
[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irNwy.png)
and update Select value from one row that difference TestType,The UserID and Set that value to Final_Test_Score column and GROUP BY UserID 
The result that I want is :

```
UserID | TotalUnitAssementScore | FinalAssessmentScore
47     | 0                      | 0
67     | 13.461538461538462     | 13.125
68     | 17.097902097902097     | 6.1875
```

Anyone can help me please, I am stuck with this for long time.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images or links to images.

Comment: format your ouput

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT USER_ID,SUM(TOTAL_UNIT_ASSESMENT),FINAL_SCORE
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY USER_ID
```

Try this.

Comment: I don't want to sum FINAL_SCORE I want get Value From TOTAL_UNIT_ASSESMENT Where TestType = 2 and UDATE FINAL_SCORE with That Value